# Can I use Koin's currentScope in Java Activities?

Tags: android, koin

I want to use **currentScope** (https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/search?q=currentscope&unscoped_q=currentscope) in an Activity written in Java.

But it doesn't seem like I can `import org.koin.android.scope.currentScope` in a Java activity.

Does anyone have any experience using Activity scopes in Java activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it this way

```
org.koin.android.scope.LifecycleOwnerExtKt.getCurrentScope()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I'm kind of stuck how to call inject on this because inject has a private access specifier. Can you please help?